# How to correctly bind SelectedItem of Datagrid to read-only List?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, selecteditem

The xaml view:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgInstances" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Instance, Mode=OneWay}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Instances}"> SelectionMode="Single"> ... etc.
```

The view-model:

```
public List<string> Instances
string instance;
public string Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (instance == null && instances.HasItems())
        {
            instance = instances[0];
        }
        if (instance != null)
        {
            return instance;
        }
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        instance = value;
    }
}
```

The view-model-class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and after the `Instances` are fetched I give  `RaisePropertyChanged("Instance");`.
The Instances are properly displayed in the datagrid, but the first item is not selected.
I don't want to add `SelectedIndex=0` because it must be via binding.
And when I change the selection in the datagrid, the setter of the databound `Instance` is not used.
That is of course also a requirement.
It is a read-only list: only the selecteditem must be databound, not any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't really use the WPF `DataGrid`, I have done in the past and seem to recollect that you can't `Bind` to the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` property... in all, it's a pretty useless property. However, I believe that you *can* `Bind` to the [`DataGrid.CurrentItem` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.currentitem.aspx) which pretty much does the same thing.

---

UPDATE >>>

I just found that the [WPF DataGrid SelectedItem binding stops working after item change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309915/wpf-datagrid-selecteditem-binding-stops-working-after-item-change) post here on StackOverflow that mentions this.

Also, it seems that you *can* use the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` property in a UI element `Binding`, eg. to display it in a `TextBox`, so it's not completely useless... just mostly useless.

---

UPDATE 2 >>>

If you *really* need to access the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` property, you can create an `AttachedProperty` to handle the `DataGrid.SelectionChanged` event.

---

UPDATE 3 >>>

My collection classes extend a custom base class, which extends the `ObservableCollection<T>` class. My custom `BaseColection<T>` class has a `CurrentItem` property of type `T`. I use this property to `Bind` to the `SelectedItem` of the collection control. However, this has the same effect as adding a property into a view model of the same type as the items in the collection being displayed, but it's just more convenient:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AudioTracks}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding AudioTracks.CurrentItem}" ... />
```

Then, if the items in the collection are small and contain *all* of the data that needs editing, I'll just use the `AudioTracks.CurrentItem` property for the editable fields on the right in my example image. However, if the data object has a lot of fields as in the image, then I just use the `AudioTracks.CurrentItem.Id` property value to send to the database to retrieve all of the values required for editing, whereas the `AudioTracks` items in the collection only hold a few values (because there can be 27,000+ of them in the collection.

Finally, regarding your linked example of a `TreeView`, I would normally use a custom `SelectedItems Attached Property` to `Bind` to the `TreeView.SelectedItems` property... If you search online, you can probably find someone's example code for this.

Comment: Thanks again. When you don't use the WPF DataGrid, what do you use instead?

Comment: I prefer to utilise what WPF provides... a custom UI with a selection panel on one side and an edit panel on the other for editing the selected item. I added a screen shot to the [Data Entities > Domain Objects > ViewModels, each with drastically different data structures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693682/data-entities-domain-objects-viewmodels-each-with-drastically-different-dat/19694623#comment29312293_19694623) post recently.

Comment: Ok - and how in your example, do you bind the selected or current item on the left with the selected or current item in the view-model? E.g. also in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3009906/138078 a simple binding to a selecteditem in the viewmodel is used.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. One more question: how do you deal with validation and/or questions for the user before the selection is changed?

Comment: I implement the [`IDataErrorInfo` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) on my data objects. I added a full answer regaring this in the [Proper validation with MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498485/proper-validation-with-mvvm/19499791#19499791) post here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi Sheridan: I use the same construct as you and I was wondering whether in `SelectedItem="{Binding AudioTracks.CurrentItem}"` it is somehow possible to replace *AudioTracks* with a placeholder for the *ItemsSource* property?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure that I understand your question... can you elaborate please?

Comment: Sorry fot not being clear enough. First of all `SelectedItem="{Binding AudioTracks.CurrentItem}"` works. But perhaps it is possible to make it even more general perhaps something like: `SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsSource}}}"` which is wrong, but do you understand what I mean?

Comment: So that the `DataContext` of `SelectedItem` would not be the same `DataContext` as `ItemsSource` has, but the list that `ItemsSource` binds to  itself.

Comment: I found it out via trial and error: `SelectedItem="{Binding ItemsSource.CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` This I put in a style for all my datagrids and listboxes: ` `<Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding ItemsSource.CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />`.

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: I want to achieve that the binding to a list is the only thing I have to do and to automatically synchronize with the current item of that list, without adding extra properties to the view model.

Comment: But then how do you access the `SelectedItem` from the view model?

Comment: `SelectedItem=CurrentItem` always and `CurrentItem` is a property of every `ObservableCollection` (like you I extended it with that property). It is exaclty the same as the binding to `AudioTracks.CurrentItem`.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying now... sorry I'm half asleep today. Personally, I'd still prefer to set that property each time so that it is easier for other developers to understand my code, but that *is* interesting. Won't that cause an error on the `DataGrid` because of its read only property?

Comment: The idea works without any errors. However I also feel that such a mini-framework somewhat overshoots the mark.